# Parallelizing with threads and blocks in CUDA

Tags: parallel-processing, cuda

I have the following simple nested for loops

```
float a[1024][1024], b[1024]

for(i=1; i < 1024; i++){
    for(j = 1; j < 1024 - i; j++){
        b[i + j] += a[i][j];    
    }
}
```

And I am trying to understand how to partition this problem using CUDA threads and thread blocks to parallelize with GPU. So far I believe I have a total of N = 522753 computations. I am not entirely sure how to proceed from here: I know the number of threads in each block should be a multiple of 32. So for instance if the number of threads per block is 1024, then I need at least 511 blocks where each thread takes a computation from 1 -> N. Can someone explain how to choose the best number of threads per block, and how to actually implement this in parallel.

Comment: @talonmies it’s from an example provided to me - not meant to actually be executed. More pseudocode than anything but I still don’t understand how I could partition into blocks and threads per block to parallelize the concept

Comment: The problem in this case is that different (i,j)-pairs want to write to the same spot. Say (3,0) and (0,3). You can use atomic_add, but it might be better to partion in a way, that use less atomic_add and has more work per thread.

Answer (score -2):

A long comment:

Edit: c matrix should be column major instead of row major and sorting should be on columns ınstead of rows but I left it as row major here for readability.

You can (for once) prepare a matrix of counts and references per workitem such that first column is count, rest is references and last column is write address

```
c[0] = {1, &a[1][1],                   &b[2]}; // b[2]
c[1] = {2, &a[1][2],&a[2][1],          &b[3]}; // b[3]
c[2] = {3, &a[1][3],&a[2][2],&a[3][1], &b[4]}; // b[4]
..
```

then sort them (for once) on their number of indices / subarray size so they become

```
   c[0]    = {1, &a[1][1],         &b[2]}    //  b[2]
   c[1]    = {1, &a[1022][1],      &b[1023]} // b[1023]
   ..
   c[k]    = {5, x1,y1,z1,t1,w1,   &b[m]} // b[m]
   c[k+1]  = {5, x2,y2,z2,t2,w2,   &b[n]} // b[n]
```

balanced on the amount of work between cuda threads of a warp/block.

Then access c matrix (1 cuda thread per row) to know which elements to add together in a plain for loop per workitem.

```
   const int length = (int)c[workitemId][0];
   for(int i=1;i<length+1;i++)
      resultOfWorkitem += *(c[workitemId][i]);
   *(c[workitemId][length+1])=resultOfWorkitem;
```

Since all sorted lists will be sorted only once, if you are going to do calculation part frequently, then this extra referencing part can be faster than using atomics and probably be cached for c and a arrays' read-only access.

If random-write address becomes problem on performance, you can sort c array on their address of last item (contiguous b indices) but this would decrease balance of work between neighboring cuda threads. Maybe this is faster, didn't test. Maybe sorting c on a's second index value makes it faster by decreasing number of reads especially when you sort each row's elements between themselves so that they become continuous with neighbor threads' reads similar to first part

```
 c[0] = {1, &a[1][1] // address x    \
 c[1] = {2, &a[1][2] // address x+1   > less than L1 cache line size 128byte?
 c[2] = {3, &a[1][3] // address x+2  /
```

preserving both continous address accessing and balanced work per workitem can be impossible.